# No Action definition for Alter table for adding foreign key constraint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

I am altering the table constraint using below query.

`ALTER TABLE MY_Table ADD (CONSTRAINT
 MT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
  (ID) REFERENCES YOUR_TABLE
  (ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION)`

I found using below url that we can not use `NO ACTION` in oracle script.

https://www.haidongji.com/2006/07/24/defining-no-action-foreign-key-constraints-in-oracle/comment-page-1/

but if we are using the below script to alter the table then in dba_constraints view,  delete_rule column value is showing as empty.

`ALTER TABLE MY_Table ADD (CONSTRAINT
 MT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
  (ID) REFERENCES YOUR_TABLE
  (ID))`

So, now my question is that how to use `NO ACTION` in oracle script so that we can get `NO ACTION` as a value in the delete_rule column of dba_constraints view.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't have a 10g database any more, but in 11gR2 at least, your second statement *does* show `DELETE_RULE` as 'NO ACTION'. Which version and patch level are you running, just in case this is a real and known issue?

Comment: Oracle 12c (12.2.0.1.0)

Comment: Then why did you tag the question for [oracle10g]? I can't reproduce this in 12cR2 either.

Answer (score 0):

This will be quite a long answer as I'm displaying what's going on in different database versions.

You'll notice that they all behave the same:

- foreign key constraint can be set to `cascade` and `set null`, and they both are displayed in `user_constraints.delete_rule` column
- `no action` is an invalid option (so you can't expect to see anything in `delete_rule`)

Here we go:

### 12c

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production              0
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                                    0
CORE    12.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                            0
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                                    0

SQL> create table your_table (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table my_table (id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete cascade;

Table altered.

SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

DELETE_RU
---------
CASCADE

SQL> alter table my_table drop constraint fk_my_your;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete set null;

Table altered.

SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

DELETE_RU
---------
SET NULL

SQL> alter table my_table drop constraint fk_my_your;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete no action;
  references your_table (id) on delete no action
                                       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00905: missing keyword


SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

no rows selected
```

### 11g

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

SQL> create table your_table (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table my_table (id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete cascade;

Table altered.

SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

DELETE_RU
---------
CASCADE

SQL> alter table my_table drop constraint fk_my_your;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete set null;

Table altered.

SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

DELETE_RU
---------
SET NULL

SQL> alter table my_table drop constraint fk_my_your;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete no action;
  references your_table (id) on delete no action
                                       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00905: missing keyword


SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

no rows selected
```

### 10g

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> create table your_table (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table my_table (id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete cascade;

Table altered.

SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

DELETE_RU
---------
CASCADE

SQL> alter table my_table drop constraint fk_my_your;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete set null;

Table altered.

SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

DELETE_RU
---------
SET NULL

SQL> alter table my_table drop constraint fk_my_your;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table my_table add constraint fk_my_your foreign key (id)
  2    references your_table (id) on delete no action;
  references your_table (id) on delete no action
                                       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00905: missing keyword


SQL> select delete_rule from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_MY_YOUR';

no rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the constraint and recreated it using below queries and found that now in delete_rule column of dba_constraints view has `NO ACTION` as value.

## Drop query

`ALTER TABLE M_SP3D_EXP_JOB_SEL_CLIS DROP CONSTRAINT 'MT_ID_FK';`

## Alter query

`ALTER TABLE MY_Table ADD (CONSTRAINT
 MT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
  (ID) REFERENCES YOUR_TABLE
  (ID))`

It is working as expected.